# D3: tickformat method to only show year

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axis

My dates for my d3 chart are month/day/year, for example: "10/1/2013"

And I'm parsing them this way: d3.time.format("%x").parse;

But how do I write a .tickFormat() method on my axis to only show the year (full year, with century)?

Answer (score 1):

Just change `%x` to `%Y` in your parsing snippet.

You can find the full documentation at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting

So something like this:

```
tickFormat: function(d) {
      var dx = data[0].values[d];
      return dx ? d3.time.format('%Y')(new Date(dx)) : '';
}
```

Of course your specifics of where to get your data etc will be different.

Answer (score 0):

When defining your x axis you can modify it with tickformat and pass in a function to return the year.

Here is a full example.

```
var width = 200, height = 200;
var data = ["10/1/2013", "10/1/2014"].map(d3.time.format("%x").parse)
var xDomain = [Math.min.apply(null, data), Math.max.apply(null, data)];
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]).domain(xDomain)
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x).tickFormat(function(time, index) { return time.getUTCFullYear()); })
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr('width', 200)
    .attr('height', 200);
svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 180 + ")")
      .call(xAxis);
```

The key line to note would be the place where we specify the tickformat of the xAxis:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x).tickFormat(function(time, index) { return time.getUTCFullYear()); })
```

Note that we specify the domain of `var x` using the parsed times in `xDomain`.

Comment: this doesnt work: .tickFormat(function(time, index) { return time.getUTCFullYear(); });

Comment: Are you calling `.scale(YOURSCALE)` on your axis, and are you calling `.domain` on `YOURSCALE`?